# GWT Development mode console output doesn't print exceptions

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, jetty

I use gwt 2.6.1 with eclipse and maven. 
I use standard development mode.

I've noticed that I am not getting stack trace exceptions and error log in standard console output.

I see Hibernate logs in console, but I can see exceptions and error, which makes debugging hard. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used old eclipse plugin. For eclipse 4.5 I've used plugin that supports only to Eclipse 4.4.

After updating plugin everythink is working back again.